# Flutter exception: Invalid image data using Image.memory()

Tags: mysql, flutter, image, dart, byte

I am trying to get image from MySQL and display using 'Image.memory' in flutter, but there is exception saying invalid image data:

```
E/FlutterJNI(12873): Failed to decode image
E/FlutterJNI(12873): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
E/FlutterJNI(12873):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.nCreate(Native Method)
E/FlutterJNI(12873):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.access$200(ImageDecoder.java:173)
E/FlutterJNI(12873):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ByteBufferSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:250)
E/FlutterJNI(12873):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmapImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1862)
E/FlutterJNI(12873):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.java:1855)
E/FlutterJNI(12873):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.decodeImage(FlutterJNI.java:431)
Reloaded 1 of 675 libraries in 750ms.

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data
```

Below is my main.dart, when I run the code, the screen shows invalid image data:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'mysql.dart';
import 'dart:convert';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter and Mysql Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  String title ='';

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  var db = new Mysql();
  var ques = '';

  void _getCustomer() {
    db.getConnection().then((conn) {
      String sql = 'select question from quiz where quizID =1;';
      conn.query(sql).then((results) {
        for(var row in results){
          setState(() {
            ques = row[0]; //<=Here
          
          });
        }
      });
      conn.close();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Uint8List code=base64Decode(ques);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child:Image.memory(base64.decode('ques')),
            
            ),
            /*Text(
              '$ques',

            ),*/
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getCustomer,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca32r.png)

When I change the ques = row[0] to ques=row['question'].toString(), the output different and another exception comes out:
[Invalid character (at character 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCLVa.png)

Has anyone run into the same problem? I would appreciate if you could help

Comment: try with other index than 0

Comment: seems nothing to do with the index,  the output still the same when i change it